# why is retrofit not returning values or print strings inside call back scopes - Android Development

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm building a very simple retrofit call but I'm getting no values in return either no errors.
The API:

```
@GET("search.php")
    fun getCocktail(@Query("s") search: String ): retrofit2.Call<List<Cocktail>>
```

The Retrofit Instance:

```
fun getCocktailService(): API {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(API::class.java)
        }
```

The View Model:

```
var data : MutableLiveData<List<Cocktail>> = MutableLiveData<List<Cocktail>>()
fun getData(){
        val retrofit = CocktailService.getCocktailService()
        print( "--- Before Call Enqueue------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        val call = retrofit.getCocktail("Margarita")
        call.enqueue(object :Callback<List<Cocktail>>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Cocktail>>, response: Response<List<Cocktail>>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    data.value = response.body()
                    print( "--- Successful------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                    response.body()?.let {
                        for(i in it){
                            if(i == null)
                                print("Null")
                            else
                                print(i.strDrink.toString())
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Cocktail>>, t: Throwable) {
                print( "--- Failed------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            }
        })



    }
```

View Model:

```
val itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
        //getCocktail("Margarita")
        itemViewModel.getData()
        itemViewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.setList(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

I tried different codes. I tried Coroutines using `viewModelScope` and other scopes.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Maybe the call succeeds (2XX status code) but the body is null... in that case, because of `?.let` your code would print nothing

Comment: The "Success" print isn't printed.

Comment: how do you know your api call isn't returning an error ? you have `if(response.isSuccessful){` but you don't have a check for if the call isn't successful ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    response.body()?.let {
                        for(i in it){
                            if(i == null)
                                print("Null")
                            else
                                print(i.strDrink.toString())
                        }
                    }
```

here remove ? question mark after body()

bcz if u place question mark there then if body is null whole block will not going to execute

it same as

```
  if(body != null){
if(body == null){
    print(null) }else {
   print("api data")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was myself.

It has nothing to do with retrofit or any android code. Problem was the api request data returns a list of "meals" which has inside a number of meals with there properties. But I was storing this data in a list directly not a data class that has a variable that is `Serialized` with "meals" name.